# Finding real coefficients of polynomial with complex roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I have been tasked with finding the just real coefficients of a polynomial with the roots:

$z_{0}=10$

$z_{1}=3-i$

$z_{2}=-8+2i$

Writing the polynomial as factors...

$(z-10)(z-3+i)(z+8-2i)$

..obviously does not work since this results in complex coefficients.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: “the real coefficients of a polynomial” or “a polynomial with only real coefficients”?

Comment: Only real coefficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not enough information, say the degree of a given polynomial.

Anyway, since it has (only) real coeficients if $a+bi$ is one root, then $a-bi$ is also a root of the polynomial.

So this polynomial is divisible with:

$$q(z)=(z-10)\color{red}{(z-3+i)(z-3-i)}\color{blue}{(z+8-2i)(z+8+2i)} $$
$$= (z-10)(z^2-6z+10)(z^2+16z+68)$$

Comment: Thanks, I think this makes sense.

Comment: And sorry, it was the smallest possible degree

Answer (score 3):

Polynomial with only real coefficients is
$$( z-10) \, ( z-2i+8)\,(z+2 i+8) \, ( z-i-3) \, ( z+i-3)\\=
{{z}^{5}}-118 {{z}^{3}}-68 {{z}^{2}}+3160 z-6800
  $$